# How to append items to a bound list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following models:

```
class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

class Products
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor page I want to loop over all products and to be able to add them to my order, like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Product p in AllProducts)
{
    <input asp-for="order.Products[i].Price">
    i++;
}
```

This works fine when creating a new order (when the list pf products is empty), but when I try to edit the order, and maybe add new products or edit the existing ones, I'm getting an `Index was out of range.` exception.
Obviously because there are more products in `AllProducts` than there are in the order's `Products` list.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting `i` from since you're doing a `foreach` not a `for` loop.

Comment: I've added the `i`

Comment: should it be written  <input asp-for="p.Price">

Comment: No, because the enumerator is for the `order.Products`

Comment: Maybe the fact that your models contain _fields_ instead of _properties_ are an issue? Also both `Products` and `Price` are private, instead of public.

Comment: It's public (edited)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing here. The loop over AllProducts doesn't do anything right? Why would you not use order.Products instead of AllProducts there? And why aren't you using a simple for with .Count instead of a foreach? Am I missing something?

Comment: @LiranFriedman why dont you use for loop with order.Products.Count restriction then you can be sure that they will be as much as order's products count

Answer (score 0):

We can do by update code. I think resolved issue. Problem was in foreach loop.

```
  int i = 0;
  foreach (Product p in AllProducts)
 {
    <input asp-for="AllProducts[i].Price">
    i++;
  }
```

Still,  you are facing the issue please share razor view.

Comment: No, this part `<input asp-for="order.Products[i].Price">` it the object that is bound to the model. It cannot be `AllProducts[i]` since it won't update the list of products in the `order` object.

Answer (score 0):

How about just looping after the last index of your current orders:

```
int i = order.Products.Count();
foreach (Product p in AllProducts)
{
    <input asp-for="order.Products[i].Price">
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While getting the order from the DB for editing, you need to fetch the associated products as well. You can use Include to fetch them. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for more details on that. Once you get the products, then you can use the products to list and also use the AllProducts to enable the use to add the products which were not in the list

Comment: I don't think there is a simple alternative

Comment: Basically, I know. But since I'm new to razor, I thought maybe there's something in razor I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification in Edit order page:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Order.Products.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="Order.Products[i].Price">
    }
```